# Extending partition on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, partition

On a Windows Server 2016 machine we have multiple partitions for separate segments of a website. However, more storage space is needed for one of the partitions, so I would like to transfer some space from the default C: drive to another partition (G:). Using the built in Disk Management program on Windows, I am unable to transfer the unallocated space obtained from C: to G: because the unallocated space is not to the right of G:. How would I go about extending the partition? The company policies are restrictive on installing unknown third party programs to manage the infrastructure, and I'm not able to find a free partition manager that works on Windows Server 16 anyways. I cannot use a bootable partition manager in order to minimize downtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this naively from Windows is not possible. Whatever program you use you'll end up with downtime as moving/resizing partitions is best done while no active processes accessing the disk, keep that in mind while I suggest the below.

Because you have too many restrictions in place I suggest that you use a bootable partition manager such as https://gparted.org, I know you don't want to have a downtime, but you'll face that wall whatever you do.

Comment: Totally agree with Noor. There are a lot of similar partition managers, but partition tool always helps us in such situations. https://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/extend-system-partition.htm

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you asked, but perhaps a solution with only native Windows Tools (and even meets your requirement on minimal downtime):

Assuming it is a directory on G that needs more space, say G:\2small

1. create a partition out of the unallocated space
2. mount this partition to a directory on G, say G:\VeryBig
3. now you can move data from G:\2small to G:\VeryBig
4. remove G\2small, rename G:\VeryBig to G:\2small

Keep in mind that only one directory gets bigger, and not the complete disk.  But it can be achieved with the Windows Disk Manager alone (or ist commandline counterpart DiskPart), and there is no need to boot to an external tool, and, if data from G:\2small is not in use, you can use this method even without reboot - that means no downtime at all.

If you like this solution, you may consider to create 2 (or even more) partions mounting each one to a Directory on drive G:.

It may be a limitation, but it may be an advantage, too, to have a capacity limit for each directory you create this way.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another workaround for Windows's inability to change partition boundaries is to use a symbolic link to a folder elsewhere.

If G: is filling up but has got a few folders like e.g. `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, and so on you can move `G:\data3` to `C:\relocated\data3` and `mklink /d G:\data3 C:\relocated\data3` so it reappears as `G:\data3`.

Not everything works this way but most things do. If this is a shared folder you must point the symlink to a share and your clients will need to be instructed to follow the symlink: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754077(v=ws.10).aspx .

Of course, this is an ugly hack but it can be a quick fill-in solution.

Comment: This is exactly how our website is structured. The root of the site is in the partition, but many subfolders lead to symbolic links. In our case, we're trying to add some files to the root and running out of space

Comment: Assuming G: isn't that big then, can't you just recreate it somewhere else. Additionally, I wouldn't recommend mounting a webroot to the root of a drive.

Comment: I'm probably going to scrap the partition system all together and use the file server resource manager to create folders with scalable folder size quotas